# .equals() method to detect duplicate array elements (tried @Override)

Tags: java

I have a simple loop that checks for any duplicate results,
where studresults holds my results , result is the object result given to the method and r is the current object from the array.
I have been using this method successfully throughout the program although it is not working in this case even though when I debug result and r , are exactly the same does anyone know why this might be? I have tried @Override already as suggested in other answers to no avail.

I am trying to stop duplicated array elements by throwing an exception.

```
for(Result r : studresults)
   {
     if(r.equals(result)) 
       {
           return false;
       }
   }
```

EDIT OK HERE IS THE WHOLE CLASS>

```
package ams.model;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;

import ams.model.exception.EnrollmentException;

public abstract class AbstractStudent implements Student {
private int studentId;
private String studentName;
private ArrayList<Course> studcourses = new ArrayList<Course>();
private ArrayList<Result> studresults = new ArrayList<Result>();


public AbstractStudent(int studentId, String studentName) {
    this.studentId = studentId;
    this.studentName = studentName;

}


public String getFullName() {


    return studentName;
}


public int getStudentId() {


    return studentId;
}


public Result[] getResults() {  

    Result[] res = studresults.toArray(new Result[0]);
    if(res.length > 0 )
    {
    return res;
    }
    return null;

}


public boolean addResult(Result result)
{
    for(Result r : studresults)
    {
        if(r.equals(result))
        {
                return false;
        }
    }

    studresults.add(result);
    return true;
}

public void enrollIntoCourse(Course c)
{
    //for re-enrollment
    if(studcourses.contains(c))
    {
        studcourses.remove(c);
        studresults.clear();
    }
    studcourses.add(c);
}

public void withdrawFromCourse(Course c) throws EnrollmentException
{
    if(studcourses.size() > 0)
    {
        studcourses.remove(c);
    }
    else
        throw new EnrollmentException();
}
public Course[] getCurrentEnrolment() 
{
    return studcourses.toArray(new Course[0]);
}


public abstract int calculateCurrentLoad();


public int calculateCareerPoints() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}

public String toString()
{
    return studentId + ":" + studentName +":" + calculateCurrentLoad();
}
```

}

Comment: Could we see Result class?

Comment: Also what is `studresults` exactly, an array or arraylist? (Or maybe some other iterable)

Comment: Not related to your equals specific question, but is throwing an exception a good idea here?

Comment: HAve I provided enough info now?

Comment: @user1511032 No - show us the `Result` class.

Answer (score 1):

Do you already override `hashCode` method in `Result`?
If you override `equals`, you have to override the `hashCode` method also to allow you return the same hashcode for the similar objects (objects which has the same value but actually different object instances).

I think the default implementation of hashcode will returns different value for a different object instances even though they have the same values.

Comment: While you're right that `hashCode` should also be overridden with `equals`, this could not be the culprit since `equals` is being used directly.

Comment: shouldn't it be the same? inherently equals will use the hashcode to compare the instances.
Maybe my mistake is assuming that equals method is overrided.

Comment: So how do I get this if statement to work when I debug it doesn't even go to end brace }, it just exits the loop completely.

Comment: @user1511032 As people noted in the comments you haven't provided enough information.

Comment: @user1511032 There are 2 options, first you override the equals method and inside the method compare the values in your Result class to make sure it is the same value. Second, override the hashcode method and return an int value which you derive from the value in your Result class (or you could simply use your primary key if any)

Comment: Its an array list so I do not have a primary key, how do I override the hashcode method?

Comment: ok I have added the whole class to try to find why this if statement doesn't work.

Comment: I am starting to think studresults.clear(); is causing the problem

Answer (score 0):

Instead I converted toString and then compared and it works???

Makes me think there was something slightly unidentical before?

New method

```
public boolean addResult(Result r)
{
    for (Result s : studresults)
    {
         String sr1 = s.toString();
         String sr2 = r.toString();
         if(sr1.equals(sr2))
         {
             return false;
         }
    }
```